# What are the advantage(s) of low-order ODE solvers as compared to high-order ones (with respect to back-propagation/gradient computation)?

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods, backpropagation

I have a system of ODE:

dy/dx = f(x, theta)
theta represents the set of parameters to be estimated, y is the output. Loss can be computed between y_predicted and y_target. This is a regression problem. I am using Euler method to compute entire y (considering y_initial = 0) for ex,
y(t+1) = y(t) + Tau * f(x, theta) and then finally computing mse loss. Then I'm using SGD to update theta.

I can use second order method for the integration instead of simple Euler scheme. But I want to know what are the advantages/disadvantages with this above Euler approach wrt back-propagation (memory requirements, computation time, etc)?

Comment: For the backpropagation you will need the partial derivatives of `f` in any case. Then it is only a slight extension of the system to compute the step derivatives using the same method as for the ODE. These could also be re-computed for every single step in the backward sweep, so that not all Jacobian matrices need to be stored. So there is no special advantage or disadvantage in the order of the method, higher-order method are more expensive but allow larger step sizes or higher accuracy.

Comment: Hi @LutzLehmann thanks for your answer. I would specifically like to know what you meant by "more expensive". For instance, more computational memory requirements or time complexity? It would also be nice if you could provide me some resources/papers I can refer to where I can get orders of space and time-complexity for fair comparisons. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Can't you just compute the derivative dy/dx of the target and process as an ordinary fitting problem ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust : Yes, in some cases, especially of only a few parameters, derivative-free methods or using divided differences for the Jacobian might be more simple. But if the target is a control function as some piecewise polynomial with the coefficients as parameters, then an AD approach will be more straight-forward.